# Is it possible to open a page from one device to another using same android application?

Tags: android

I need to know is it possible to open a view on multiple machines by giving some command or opening of that page on an another machine (might be the server) using same android application.

What I want exactly is for eg.- like for around 20 people with same android application installed. I would like my admin person to open up a view of that application in all those 20 devices at the same time just by opening it on his machine.
Basically, I want to show the same thing I was viewing to every person using that applicaton at that time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you intent to show web pages in all the devices?

Comment: not exactly a web page, just a view page of my application to all the devices.

Comment: Do you want to create a new app or are you fine using anyother?

Comment: yes, i want to create a new personalized app of mine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) service. It is Google analog for wide-known Apple Push Notification Service. It is what you need, as I think.
Bad point is in necessity of creation some back-end to stay in connect with your devices.

Actually, you will be able to do what you want from BroadcastReceiver attached to special message, which will be sent by Google service.

If you need some more information - read api documentation and [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)

Comment: C2DM is good, but for C2DM, i need an google account for every device and also working internet connection, is there is any other way to communicate b/w client and server without involving third party and no internet connection.

Comment: And how do you want to send some "signal" to device without using Internet? Bluetooth is not suitable - you'll have such a hell with pairing and so on.